# FireDAC query->Open crashes on Android

Tags: firemonkey, firedac, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a multi-device FMX Form that I'm building in Embarcadero C++Builder.  The app opens a local SQLite database file (`my_local.db`) and performs queries against it.

It works fine on iOS, but crashes on Android.  No error to catch.  The SQLite file exists and the `ShowMessage` inside the `#if` statement returns `"/data/user/0/com.embarcadero.Project1/files/my_local.db"`.

If I comment out the `query->Open()` statement, the code runs and the app won't crash.

```
#if defined(_PLAT_IOS) || defined(_PLAT_ANDROID)
Form1->FDConnection1->Params->Values["ColumnMetadataSupported"] = "False";
Form1->FDConnection1->Params->Values["Database"] = System::Ioutils::TPath::Combine(System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath(), "my_local.db");
if (FileExists(Form1->FDConnection1->Params->Values["Database"])) {
    ShowMessage(Form1->FDConnection1->Params->Values["Database"]);   // if file there show its path
}
#endif

TFDQuery *query;
query = new TFDQuery(NULL);
query->Connection = Form1->FDConnection1;
query->SQL->Text = "SELECT * FROM info";
query->Open();
```

Any pointers or suggestions on how to catch this error?

Comment: Crashes *HOW* exactly?  You say there is no error, but obviously there has to be one, or you wouldn't be having problems.

Comment: I get the app splash screen and then app dies and goes away.  Commenting out the query->Open() and the app keeps trucking along (of course the data from the query is missing).  ;-)

Comment: Where exactly are you calling this code from? Do you have the same problem if you delay the code until the app is actually fully initialized and visible to the user? Have you tried wrapping the `Open()` in a `try/catch` block? Can you run the app in the IDE debugger and see an error message?

Comment: Hi Remy - yes, I tried a try/catch to no avail.  This code is running in "_fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)".  In the morning I will move it and see if the delay helps.  It didn't occur to me because it worked fine in IOS and Win32.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you try catching the error using `catch (...)` or `catch (const Exception &`)? It does make a difference.  And yes, I would not suggest opening a database in a Form's constructor.

Comment: Remy - I moved the code as you suggested and it runs now.  I'm going to show it as the answer with a little more detail for the next guy.  I'll try more "catch" work also to see if I can get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Remy's suggestion to move the code out of the Form's constructor solved the unknown crash on Android.  Now it runs but gives the error shown below (this is probably the error that was causing the crash originally that I wasn't able to catch).  The error message is shown below.  The solution is simple - put a TFDGUIxWaitCursor on the form. After doing that it runs fine.

[image]